# Orientation preserving and orientation reserving of a parameterisation of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

The definition states:

> Let $\mathbf{x}:\left [ a,b \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a piecewise $\mathit{C}$ path. We say that another $\mathit{C}$ path $\mathbf{y}:\left [ c,d \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a $\mathbf{reparameterisation}\ of \ \mathbf{x}$ if there is a one-to-one and onto function $u:\left [ c,d \right ]\rightarrow \left [ a,b \right ]$ of class $\mathit{C}$, with inverse $u^{-1}:\left [ a,b \right ]\rightarrow \left [ c,d \right ]$ that is also of class C, such that $\mathbf{y}\left ( t \right )=\mathbf{x}\left ( u\left ( t \right ) \right )$; that is $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}\circ u$

The velocity vector is thus

$\mathbf{y}'\left ( t \right )=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\left ( \mathbf{x}\left ( u\left ( t \right ) \right ) \right )=\mathbf{x}'\left ( u\left ( t \right ) \right )u'\left ( t \right )$

The speed is just the magnitude of the velocity vector, giving

$\left \| \mathbf{y'} \left ( t \right )\right \|=\left | u'\left ( t \right ) \right |\left \| \mathbf{x'} \left ( u\left ( t \right ) \right )\right \|$

Here's what my text claims:

> Since u is one-one, it follows that either $u\left ( t \right )\geq 0 \forall t\in\left [ a,b \right ]$ or $u\left ( t \right )\leq 0 \forall t\in\left [ a,b \right ]$

Why is this claim true?

Comment: What's the text? Looks like some conditions are missing.

Comment: $u'(t)\geqslant 0$ or $u'(t)\leqslant 0$, right?

Comment: You have that $u$ is a diffeomorphism and so $u'(t)\ne 0$ for all $t\in (a,b)$.

Comment: @Zircht
I suspect there is a typo in the text(book).